# In file browser: connect to ssh server via other ssh server

Tags: networking, server, ssh

in my file browser I have problems connecting remotely to a machine which sits behind a nasty firewall. Usually in a terminal our procedure to connect to that server goes via an ssh connection within another ssh session connecting to the "portal" to that server. In the terminal it goes like this:

```
ssh -p portNumber myName@portalServer.com/
ssh serverBehindFirewall
```

But how can I do the same using Ubuntu's "connect to server" function? I can connect easily to the portal server like this:

```
ssh://myName@portalServer.com:portNumber/
```

But how do I add in the additional ssh connection?
Is it possible to have something like:

```
ssh://myName@portalServer.com:portNumber/ssh://serverBehindFirewall
```

Looking forward for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ssh port forwarding on the console, so you could connect directly from your computer to serverBehindFirewall.

```
# This will open a tunnel from your local machine, port 22022 to port
# 22 on serverBehindFirewall. You'll need to leave this window open.
localmachine:~$ ssh -L22022:serverBehindFirewall:22 myName@portalServer.com

# now you can open a second terminal on your local machine and
# connect directly to serverBehindFirewall on localhost:22022
localmachine:~$ ssh -p 22022 userbehindFirewall@localhost
```

After the first step, you can also use the "connect to server" function with `ssh://userbehindFirewall@localhost:22022/`. If you want it as a permanent solution, you could use something like autossh ([Homepage](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), [Guide](https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/))